# Do 2.5" Laptop hard drives get power over the ribbon cable?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

Took the hard drive of an old laptop and was surprised to not find any power cable, just an IDE connector. Do 2.5" laptop drives get power over the connector or is this a proprietary connector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they do. That is standard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't know this before

Answer (score 4):

It's a standard 44 pin connector. The first 40 pins are the same as desktop IDE, for data. The last four carry power. Converting to and from a desktop style 40 pin connector + molex power is trivial, and adapters were cheap.